# Convert jsonObject to Map in scala programming language

Tags: json, scala, gson, deserialization

I am working in Scala programming language.

I want to convert json object to Map[String, String]

My jsonObject looks like

```
{"Key1":"Val1","Key2":"Val2","Key3":"Val3"}
```

I want to have a Map like

```
Map("Key1" -> "Val1", "Key2" -> "Val2", "Key3" -> "Val3")
```

How can i do this?
Note: I am using Gson for my other json manipulation

Thanks

Comment: There are tons decoders in scala. I like [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) a lot they have a nice documentation as well. Also look st this please [arse get request to jsonarray in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651708/432903) and [Pretty JSON multi reg to one line JSON multi reg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50219457/432903)

Comment: are you also using java or purely scala if you're using gson?

Comment: likely a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2779251/5986907 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/8054018/5986907

Comment: I solved it using JSON.parseFull(dataString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jackson object Mapper for this.

https://www.alexkras.com/parse-json-object-to-map-in-scala-using-jackson/